# How to cycle through set amount of numbers and loop using geometry nodes?

Tags: node-editor, geometry, loop

I've been working on a 'digital stopmotion' setup using geometry nodes, it basically cycles through some selected objects to create a stop-motion effect. Currently, it goes through these 5 objects to create a flame, but only does it once since it's based on seconds so the number keeps going up. I'm looking for a way to use the "Number of Meshes" Integer to give it a limit and loop it back to 0.

I know I can use an Integer to just key the numbers going up and down but it would be great to have this automated for more control.

Screenshot with my current setup:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you move (or link) your objects into a collection, then this sort of arrangement will automatically cycle through them in their name-order:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

hopefully this is what you want to achieve?

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you! This is exactly doing what my setup currently does as wel (yours is a smarter setup though haha). The issue is that it only does this once, Im looking for a way to make it loop (cycling from object 1-2-3-4-5-1-2-3-4-5 etc.) without having to key the numbers myself

Comment: To make it loop simply pass the "frame" through "math: modulo" to convert infinite to periodic sequence.